# How far to take abstraction in React Native and/or similar frameworks of a similar nature

Tags: reactjs, react-native, abstraction

I have been creating various webapps/mobile apps etc in Angular, React, Vue etc. I was wondering what the general consensus is on abstraction within React Native and other similar frameworks.

I have started using redux which does a major about of abstraction and adds alot of boilerplate but with it alot of control and separation of logic and components which is good. But should I be trying to abstract even my own components, small amounts of math logic etc?

Is there a general guideline or principal bigger players/corps/devs follow as a ruleset to ensure everyone is on the same page?

I would like to ensure that I build the best habits within programming so I thought stackoverflow, having such a vast array of different programmers from different areas and backgrounds would be a good place to enquire

Comment: This question can’t  have a concrete answer and is subjective.  However, read up on the single responsibility principle.  That’s generally the guiding principle for abstraction level.  That being said there is still plenty of wiggle room and everyone is different.

Comment: Appreciate the response, I will have a read

Comment: Another good guideline is unit testing.  If you find it hard to unit test your classes/modules/whatever then they are probably doing too much.

Comment: *Is there a general guideline or principal bigger players/corps/devs follow as a ruleset to ensure everyone is on the same page?* - I believe this is not something that can be taught, also nobody is on the same page. An abstraction is suitable as long as it provides advantages and doesn't provide disadvantages. It's not easy to understand all advantages and disadvantages are without experiencing them. Analyzing well-written code and figuring out why it was done this way and not another is a way to get some ideas.